# How to pass PDFKit readable stream into request's post method?

Tags: node.js, stream, node-request, node-pdfkit

My app needs to create a PDF file and then upload it to another server. The upload happens down the line via the `post` method from the `request` NPM package. Everything works fine if I pass in an `fs.createReadStream`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const params = {file: fs.createReadStream('test.pdf')};
api.uploadFile(params);
```

Since PDFKit instantiates a read stream as well, I'm trying to pass that directly into the post params like this:

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.text('steam test');
doc.end();

const params = {file: doc};

api.uploadFile(params);
```

However, this produces an error:

> TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [Function]

If I look at PDFKit source code I see (in coffeescript):

```
class PDFDocument extends stream.Readable
```

I'm new to streams and it's clear I'm not understanding the difference here. To me if they are both readable streams, they should both be able to be passed in the same way.